# No properties are mapped for type using csvHelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have two methods that return list of EmployeeCsv and CardCsv.

```
public class EmployeeCsv
{
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
}

public class CardCsv
{
    public string MaxCharge { get; set; }
    public string MaxDiscount { get; set; }
}

public List<EmployeeCsv> GetEmployeeList() {} // returns list of EmployeeCsv
public List<CardCsv> GetCardList() {} // returns list of CardCsv
```

I wanted to declare one type list for those two methods.
So I changed them like below

```
public interface ITest {}
public class EmployeeCsv : ITest
{
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
}

public class CardCsv : ITest
{
    public string MaxCharge { get; set; }
    public string MaxDiscount { get; set; }
}

public List<ITest> GetEmployeeList() {}
public List<ITest> GetCardList() {}
```

Main:

```
void main()
{
    var records = new List<ITest>();
    records = GetEmployeeList();
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) => true;
        csv.WriteRecords(records); // error here
    }
}
```

I get an error on saving after adding interface to those two classes.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you not tell us the error message for any particular reason ? To most people error messages are useful

Comment: subject is the error message.
CsvHelper.WriterException: 'No properties are mapped for type 'ProjectName.ITest'.'

Comment: CsvHelper is complaining about your type doesn't have property for the columns name it found on `ITest`. Post your csv layout and it may help. Mostly, CSV should have fixed columns, so your intention of combining two csv by ITest seems confusing.

Comment: That is all of ITest layout.
Nothing else.
I added it because I want to delcare just one type List<something that can be used for EmployeeCsv and CardCsv>().

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `CsvHelper` doesn't know the instance of the list items. You're telling it to process `ITest` items.

Consider the following:

```
var records = new List<ITest> { new EmployeeCsv(), new CardCsv() };
```

This is valid code. Now put yourself in CsvHelper's position. How would it create a CSV out of the items? Would it handle them as `Employee`, or `Card`? Neither. All it knows is that the items were `ITest` (a blank interface). Hence your error.

Instead complicating it with `ITest`, you're better off leaving the list items as their concrete types, but treating them as `IEnumerable`.

```
// Leave them as the derived types
public List<EmployeeCsv> GetEmployeeList() { .. }
public List<CardCsv> GetCardList() { .. }

void Main() {
    // Notice the IEnumerable so we can reuse WriteToFile()
    IEnumerable items = GetEmployeeList();
    WriteToFile(items); // employees

    items = GetCardList();
    WriteToFile(items); // cards
}
void WriteToFile(IEnumerable records) {
    ...
    csv.WriteRecords(records);
}
```

This way, CsvHelper can actually inspect the list and figure out the type, without the `ITest` confusion.

**Edit:**
You should probably create a generic method, that way you can limit your items to `ITest` if you really want to, or you can leave it open.

```
// This needs to stay as its concrete type.
public List<EmployeeCsv> GetEmployeeList() { .. }

void Main() { 
    WriteToFile(GetEmployeeList()); 
}

// Get rid of the 'where' to make it accept things other than ITest.
void WriteToFile<T>(IEnumerable<T> records) where T : ITest
{   ...
    csv.WriteRecords(records);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I also removed interface. But I have found solution by making records as List<object>
and making all methods returning List<object>.

Comment: It's still worth considering the generic version in my edit, as that would give you the ability to strongly-type your list (and restrict the method)